# Para que serve o arquivo __init__.py em módulos no python?

Tags: python

Estou começando a trabalhar mais fundo com o Python e tenho percebido muitos projetos com arquivos `__int__.py` nas pastas, e muitas vezes estão em branco.

Qual a finalidade desses arquivos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ele é parte de um pacote. Veja a [documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

> Os arquivos `__init__.py`  são obrigatórios para fazer o Python tratar
>   os diretórios que contem os pacotes, isto e feito para evitar
>   diretórios com nomes em comum, tal como `string`, que involuntariamente
>   se esconde nos módulos validos, aqueles que serão pesquisados no
>   caminho. No caso mais simples, o arquivo `__init__.py` apenas pode ser um
>   arquivo vazio, mas ele também executa o código de inicialização para o
>   pacote ou defini a variável `__all__`, descrita mais tarde.

Answer (score 3):

Os ficheiros __init__.py servem para declarar ao interpretador python que a diretoria onde se encontram contêm ficheiros python do programa. Exemplo:

```
diretoria/
    __init__.py
    ficheiro_a.py
    ficheiro_b.py
    ficheiro_c.py
```