# Python - Dúvida sobre importações na criação de bibliotecas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se eu estou criando uma biblioteca, e nela eu coloco `import json`, no meu main (o meu arquivo principal) eu teria que importar o `json` ou só dou import da minha biblioteca mesmo?

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa importar de novo:

```
#arquivo teste1.py
import random
print ("Olá")

#arquivo teste2.py
import teste1
for i in range(0,5):
    print(random.randint(0,i))
```

Quando rodo pelo prompt:

```
C:\Users\user_name\Desktop> python teste2.py
Olá
Traceback (most recent call kast):
  File "teste2.py", line 3, in (module)
    print(random.randint(0,i))
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

Independente se precisa importar de novo ou não, tem algumas coisas que temos que ter em mente:

1) Uma biblioteca nunca é importada duas vezes. Se ela já foi importada, ela não será carregada de novo.

```
#teste1.py
print ("Olá")

#teste2.py
import teste1
import teste1
```

Ao executar o teste2.py pelo prompt, minha saída é:

```
C:\Users\user_name\Desktop> python teste2.py
Olá
```

Repare que ele só executou o teste1.py uma única vez.

2) Se quiser usar várias biblioteca iguais em vários arquivos, você pode fazer os imports no `__init__.py`. Veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321291/importa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-arquivo-init-py/321311#321311) ou [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96608/para-que-serve-o-arquivo-init-py-em-m%C3%B3dulos-no-python).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!